# Parameters for osm2po web service to route for walking

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, osm2po

I have started the osm2po web service using the jar file. In the configuration file, I could see different parameters related to walking but not sure what each one does.

I am trying to call the web service through Python program and parse the response to get relevant data. So, far I was able to retrieve route between source and target. But I want to hit the web service and change the parameters to walking.

My URL looks like this,

http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=fr&source=40.6413,-73.7781&target=40.7589,-73.9851&format=geojson

I have gone through the examples given in osm2po.de website where example URL is for points which can be reached with given time by a car

?cmd=fx&source=53.5,10.0&findShortestPath=false&maxCost=0.2&format=geojson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data in the graph file. In order to include or exclude road types modify the **osm2po.config** file.

See [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49812/calculate-costs-based-on-way-difficulty#answer-49840). It's a similar question for bike routing

But dont use **maxSpeedOverrides** anymore, it's deprecated in newer versions of osm2po.